# Error in Next-Auth (Auth Js) in Next Js build

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

[auth][error] UnknownAction: Cannot parse action at /session .Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#unknownaction
at H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\chunks\985.js:17:51838
at tG (H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\chunks\985.js:17:52153)
at iZ (H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\chunks\985.js:373:46219)
at i1 (H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\chunks\985.js:373:53850)
at H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\chunks\985.js:373:54713
at m (H:\Next projects\ghost.next\server\app\account\page.js:505:18008)
at em (H:\Next projects\ghost\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:131226)
at H:\Next projects\ghost\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142926
at Array.toJSON (H:\Next projects\ghost\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:146504)
at stringify ()

**this is the Error i got**.
here is my .env file
AUTH_SECRET = "*****"
DATABASE_URL="******"

NEXTAUTH_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

*note that if i remove the NEXTAUTH_URL in i get another error of Untrusted Host!*

anyways what should i do?
btw my application works fine in dev mode.